# Image slider sometimes not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in php and I have a problem with my website.

I have a code for image slider in java script and I have set the slider to slide after every second but sometimes it moves automatically fast and then mouse over event also not work. It happens very rarely.

Here is my java script code

```
'use strict';

$(function(){
var width =300;

var pause =3000;
var currentSlide =1;

var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

var interval;

function startSlider(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width},1000,function(){
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide===$slides.length){
                currentSlide=1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0);
            }
        });
    },pause);
}
function stopSlider(){
    clearInterval(interval);

}
$slider.on('mouseenter',stopSlider).on('mouseleave',startSlider);
startSlider();

});
```

HTML code

```
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/student/main.css">
<script src="http://localhost:8080/student/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/student/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<h1 class="text-muted">Some of the Beautiful Places</h1>
</div>
<div id="slider">
<ul class="slides">
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/a.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/2.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/3.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/4.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/5.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://localhost:8080/student/slides/6.jpg" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="#"/></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and css file

```css
#slider{
 width:300px;
 height:168px;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

#slider .slides{
 display: inline-block;
 width : 6720px;
 height:168px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#slider .slide{
 float:left;
 list-style-type:none;
 width:300px;
 height:168px;
}
```

Comment: and someone please clear me about the setinterval and clearInterval

Comment: Why did you tag php though

Answer (score 0):

works fine, how to reproduce bug ?

```js
'use strict';

$(function(){
var width =300;

var pause =1000;
var currentSlide =1;

var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

var interval;

function startSlider(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width}, 1000, function(){
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide===$slides.length){
                currentSlide=1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0);
            }
        });
    },pause);
}
function stopSlider(){
    clearInterval(interval);

}
$slides.hover(stopSlider, startSlider);
startSlider();

});
```

```css
#slider{
 width:300px;
 height:168px;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

#slider .slides{
 display: inline-block;
 width : 6720px;
 height:168px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#slider .slide{
 float:left;
 list-style-type:none;
 width:300px;
 height:168px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<h1 class="text-muted">Some of the Beautiful Places</h1>
</div>
<div id="slider">
<ul class="slides">
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/300/168" class="zoom"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img  src="#"/></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Slider goes automatically fast sometimes

Comment: Run this code and it will not stop on mouse over after 5 mins...You can check it here